# Segmentation fault while initiating a C program through PHP

Tags: php, c, apache, gdb, segmentation-fault

OS: ubuntu 11.10
Webserver: Apache
Code: PHP

Hello I am trying to "exec" a C code through PHP web page. When I run the same C code directly on terminal, it works fine, but when I "exec" it through PHP, I get a segmentation fault.

Any idea why such behavior? My C code is doing small "malloc"s at a few places. The code never the less works fine on directly executing through terminal using ./a.out

Is there a way for me to gdb the C code, when PHP tries to execute it?

Thanks

Comment: You can attach gdb to a running process, but if it runs to quickly it is hard. A better solution is to make sure that when the program crashes that it generates a core dump that can be used by gdb to help debug.

Comment: @Joachim if you have problems with a program dying before you can attach the debugger and it's relatively simple just create a local flag variable explicitly set to 1, then put something like a while (var) sleep(1); spinloop.  Once you attach the debugger you can set the variable to 0 and the program will continue on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell without actually seeing the code. Are you sure your program doesn't leak? Are you able to add some debug console output to see when/where it crashes? Does your program try to access any ressources (like files, ports, etc.)? Are there sufficient rights for the web server's user (or whoever runs the php script) to actually execute it properly?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to open a file in my C code. Any pointers to how I can allow the web server user to open files etc..?

Comment: There can be several reasons for this to fail. The web server (or the php interpreter to be more specific) might call your executable from another dir using an absolute or relative path. E.g. your executable might sit in `/home/` but it will be run from `/usr/bin/` (or wherever). Also, regarding user rights, if your web server is in the same group, chmod the file to 550. If it's in a different group as well, set it to 555 (the data file, not the program; the program should be 770 or 777).

Comment: Also, just as an added security measure: Don't put the executable (and the data possibly too) in a path that is accessible from the web, to avoid someone executing or opening the files directly.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. The problem was with the relative paths in my C code. Its working once I specified the full path to the input file. Thanks for the insights!

Comment: @user940154 That is a sign that you didn't check return values properly. If a function you call can return an error of some kind (like `fopen` returning `NULL`) then always check it and do something sensible in case of an error.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Sure, you are absolutely right, and I really do take all care with C. New to php, and using exec from php. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it is a user permissions error.  Your web server will run as a different user (nobody, wwwrun or similar).  Try doing an su to the web server user, and running the C program as that user.

Comment: Running the web server as a super user might be a bad idea, at least if it's not just done for testing. Just wanting to add, that this is no permanent solution.

Comment: Neither was it my suggestion!  su to the web server user so you can see how the program behaves as that user.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is enabling core dump file creation and read the core dump into gdb after the exe crash. To enable core dump creation see what 'ulimit' does.

BTW: One possible reason for your program crash can be uninitialized variables, in particular pointer variables.